# Why unintialized array elements are not 0 always in C

Tags: arrays, c

I input 4566371 and find out that uninitialized array elements are not 0 as said in our texts

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

// Function to print the digit of
// number N
void printDigit(long long int N)
{
 // To store the digit
 // of the number N
 int array_unsorted[MAX];//array_unsorteday for storing the digits
 int i = 0;//initializing the loop for the first element of array_unsorted[]
 int j, r;

 // Till N becomes 0,we will MOD the Number N
 while (N != 0) {

     // Extract the right-most digit of N
     r = N % 10;

     // Put the digit in array_unsorted's i th element
     array_unsorted[i] = r;
     i++;

     // Update N to N/10 to extract
     // next last digit
     N = N / 10;
 }

 // Print the digit of N by traversing
 // array_unsorted[] reverse
 for (j =MAX; j >=0; j--)
 {
     printf("%d ", array_unsorted[j]);
 }
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
 long long int N;
 printf("Enter your number:");
 scanf("%lld",&N);
 printDigit(N);
 return 0;
}
```

output:
Enter your number:4566371
77 0 8 32765 4 5 6 6 3 7 1
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.406 s
Press any key to continue.
The other values should be o right?Why 77,0,32765 this way?Why not all are 0?like 0 0 0 0 4 5 6 6 3 7 1?

Comment: Why?  Because that takes run-time overhead.  If your texts say 'initialized to zero', either you're reading them incorrectly, or they're worthless.  In the former case - you need to understand the difference between auto variables and others (static, or at file scope).  Your array_unsorted is automatic.

Comment: Because the language specification does not require them to be initialized

Comment: @access violation bro...even Neso Academy said that "initialized to 0"

Comment: Nevertheless, anything that claims stack objects are automatically initialized is simply **wrong** about a basic language feature - as you have discovered.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As noted in other answers, you may want to initialize your integer array.  Whether or not you do that, you might want to replace the for loop statement conditions of:

```
for (j =MAX; j >=0; j--)
```

with:

```
for (j = i - 1; j >=0; j--) /* Start at the place the digit storage ended */
```

That way, you are not moving into array elements that were not used in the digit storage portion of your function.

Answer (score 5):

An array of integers declared inside a function has indeterminate values if it is *uninitialized.*  If a similar array is declared at global scope, outside all functions, it will be initialized with zeros by default.

To make an array that is always initialized to zeros, do this:

```
int array_unsorted[MAX] = {0};
```

This works because in C, `= {0}` will initialize all values with zero.  If you say `= {10, 20}` it will initialize the first two elements as written, and the rest to zero.

Comment: It should be `= {0}` for C. `= {}` is not allowed by the standard.

Comment: @Unmitigated: thank you, corrected.  My C++ was leaking.

Comment: The value of uninitialized objects is specified to be *indeterminate*, not *unspecified*. In C implementations where there is no trap value of the object’s type, these are the same, but they are not the same generally.

Comment: See [§6.2.4 ¶6 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p6) for corroboration of the previous comment (which was not written by me). Also, see the definition of [indeterminate value](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2) and [unspecified value](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.3).

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly reserved a memory space for your array *array_unsorted* but the memory has not been cleaned before use. This memory reserved it was probably used by another function or variable before yours! This is why it already has some values in it. You should set it to 0 manually before starting to use it.

Comment: It wasn't "used by another program" in the sense that it contains any data from that other program.  That'd be a major security hole.  Memory is typically zeroed out before being assigned to a new process.  However, there's plenty of code using the newly-zeroed stack before we get into printDigit, so they will leave the memory dirty.  If you want zero, you need to set zero.

Comment: True! my mistake, used by another function or variable would be more accurate. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: Instead of correcting your mistake at the end of your answer, I suggest that you correct your mistake by overwriting your answer.

Comment: I've integrated the edit into the body of the answer.